# IS DataNucleus GAE JPQL different from JPA1 standard?

Tags: java, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpql, datanucleus

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM SSUser u WHERE u.emailId=?1")
    .setParameter(1, email);
```

I thought this would be a valid query, but then I get:

```
No results for query: SELECT FROM SSUser u WHERE u.emailId=?1
```

What's the right way to express this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is correct but positional params are currently broken in GAE/J. This is **Issue [128](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=128): Positional parameters don't work (JPQL)**. Workaround: use named parameters.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM SSUser u WHERE u.emailId = :email")
    .setParameter("email", email);
```